# Does Qt 5.6 and QtCreator work with MS Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: visual-studio, qt, configuration

I'm trying to used the prebuilt version of Qt 5.6 and Qt Creator with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015

When I try to compile one of the example Qt programs (filesystembrowser) I get the following error message:
**Error while building/deploying project filesystembrowser (kit: Desktop Qt 5.6.0 MSVC2015 64bit) When executing step "Make"**

and the Issue

**Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in the kit options.**

When I check Tools/Options/Kits, all of the auto detected compilers MSVC2015 32bit and 64bit have a red warning icon and in the Compiler field the message 
"No Compiler"

Is it possible that the prebuilt version of Qt 5.6 is not compatible with MSVC 2015 Community edition? or am I doing something else wrong??

Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01055

Installed Version: Community

Comment: It's compatible with VS2015 community. I use it every day. :-) Did you install Qt before or after VS2015?

Comment: Also, check the compiler tab for more info. A "kit" is a combination of a Qt version, compiler, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe choose one of the offline installers instead of the online installers. It appears Qt 5.6.0 is built for VS2015. http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2

Answer (score 0):

Use **Qt Visual Studio Tools** visual studio extension. it will do all the work, you can create a new Qt application right in the visual studio or import an existing one (+debugging, ...)

link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools-19123